# Change the function of the browser's back button two out of three times

Tags: javascript

I have a `Javascript` (see below) that changes the url of the browser's back button.

The problem is, I want this `Javascript` to work two out of three times.

In other words, 33% redirects to the REAL previous page

I need it to work in all browsers.

```html
<script>
(function(window, location) {
history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname+"#!/history");
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);

window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
  if(location.hash === "#!/history") {
    history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
    setTimeout(function(){
      location.replace("http://example.com");
    },0);
  }
}, false);
}(window, location));
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: _“In other words, 33% redirects to the REAL previous page”_ - in other words, f*ck with the user’s rightful expectations only 2/3 of the time, haha. // Do you need this to be alternating and/or _absolutely_ stick to a 1/3 : 2/3 distribution, or would you be happy enough with just randomly deciding each time? (Math.random would be a good keyword, if the latter.)

Comment: Hi Sagar! XD Better deciding randomly each time. But in each click there is this probability 2/3 and 1/3. Thank U !

Comment: Math.random gives a value in the range of [0, 1[ - so a check for < .33 is basically all you need. (One could discuss whether that should be <=, or a slightly different number … but you’d need a really large number of executions before that would actually make much of a difference.)

Comment: what's the purpose of this feature? Sounds like something that will really annoy your users, and/or make them think your app is broken.

Comment: Hi Sagar! Can you show what the complete code would look like? With math.random Thanks for answering, I appreciate your time